# Inject custom service into Behat context

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, behat

Is it possible to build and inject my own, custom services into a Behat Context class?

I'm integrating Behat with Symfony2, and I can inject Symfony's services into my contexts like so:

```
contexts:
    - Meeebu\MyBundle\Features\Security\Context\SecurityContext:
        session:    '@session'
```

provided that the `Behat\Symfony2Extension` is registered.

I'm also using [Behat Page Object Extension](http://behat-page-object-extension.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that injects `Page` objects into Context constructor directly, so my constructo currently looks like this:

`public function __construct(Session $session, Homepage $homepage, WelcomeAdmin $welcomeAdminPage)`

Now, I'd like to use my owe custom services in the Context class.

How can I create, register, and inject them in Behat?

Comment: Easier options for you. [Accessing services, parameters, entity manager and document manager in FeatureContext file](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/fnrt/accessing-services-parameters-entity-manager-and-document-manager-in-feature-context-file), [Enabling service container in FeatureContext](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/yw0n/enabling-service-container-in-feature-context) and [Behat](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/behat)

Comment: @BentCoder, I also cosidered it at first, but since I'm using `Behat\Symfony2Extension` it does not implement `ContainerAwareInterface` as it's now possible to inject SF2 services directly in the configuration file. Also, i wanted to inject services that are not part of Symfony's container, but are unique to my Behat installation only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create and register a behat extension: https://github.com/Behat/Behat/blob/2.5/src/Behat/Behat/Extension/ExtensionInterface.php

and then register your service (or load an yml/xml/etc. file) in the load method.
and then add an extension class to the behat.yml, to the extensions section.

Comment: Note this answer works for Behat 2 only. In Behat 3 there's a different interface you need to implement. In Behat 3 you can avoid writing a custom extension with https://packagist.org/packages/zalas/behat-no-extension

Comment: @JakubZalas, this is a great "NoExtension" extension, thanks ;p

Comment: This does not answer how one would get dependencies within a *context* (Zalas' extension does help though).